# Control print order of matrix terms in Sympy

Tags: matrix, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I have a matrix addition with several terms that I want to display in a Jupyter Notebook.  I need the order of terms to match the standard notation - in my case, of linear regression.  But, the terms do not, by default, appear in the correct order for my purpose, and I would like to ask how to control the order of display of matrices in a matrix addition (`MatAdd`) term in Sympy.  For example, here we see that Sympy selects a particular order for the terms, that appears to be based on the values in the `Matrix`.

```py
from sympy import MatAdd, Matrix
A = Matrix([1])
B = Matrix([0])
print(MatAdd(A, B, evaluate=False))
```

This gives

```
Matrix([[0]]) + Matrix([[1]])
```

Notice the matrix terms do not follow the order of defintion or the variable names.

Is there anything I can do to control the print output order of `Matrix` terms in a `MatAdd` expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `init_printing` to chose from a few options. In particular, the `order` keyword should control how things are shown on the screen vs how things are stored in SymPy objects.

Now comes the differences: by setting `init_printing(order="none")` printers behave differently. I believe this is some bug.

For example, I usually use Latex rendering when using Jupyter Notebook:

```py
from sympy import MatAdd, Matrix, init_printing
init_printing(order="none")
A = Matrix([1])
B = Matrix([0])
add = MatAdd(A, B, evaluate=False)
print(add)
# out: Matrix([[0]]) + Matrix([[1]])
display(add)
# out: [1] + [0]
```

Here you can see that the latex printer is displaying the elements as they are stored (check `add.args`), whereas the string printer is not following that convention...

Comment: Hmm - interesting, with Sympy 1.6.1 I get the same output as you from IPython, but I get `[0] + [1]` for the second when running in Jupyter.

Comment: Also - I see Sympy does not document `"none"` (the string) as a keyword argument, at least in the `init_printing` docstring.

Comment: I discovered it some times ago by looking at the source code when I needed to have a 1-1 correspondence between what was shown on the screen and what was stored in a object. It is still undocumented on SymPy 1.10.

Comment: This is a common feature request so it should be documented (and fixed if needed).

Comment: Am I right in saying, though, that there is still no working fix for display order in the notebook?

Comment: I think it would be best to open a github issue and discuss there.

Comment: issue opened: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23549

Comment: Updating to Sympy 1.10 replicated the behavior here in the notebook, but exposed a new error : https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23552